# Invertible functions on a proper variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It seems well-known that for a smooth proper geometrically integral variety $X$ over a number field $k$, the invertible functions on $\bar{X} := X \times _k \bar{k}$ are the nonzero constants, i.e., $\bar{k}[X]^* = \bar{k}^*$.

Does anyone have a proof or reference of this result? I've tried using the valuative criterion of properness but I couldn't get anywhere.

Furthermore, what can we say about the invertible rational functions $\bar{k}(X)^*$ in this case? Would it also be $\bar{k}^*$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reference:

> **Lemma** ([Stacks 0BUG](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BUG)): Let $k$ be a field. Let $X$ be a proper scheme over $k$.
>
> 1. $A=H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra.
> 2. $A=\prod_{i=1,\cdots,n} A_i$ is a product of Artinian local $k$-algebras, one factor for each connected component of $X$.
> 3. If $X$ is reduced, then $A=\prod_{i=1,\cdots,n} k_i$ is a product of fields, each a finite extension of $k$.
>
> ...
>
> 8. If $X$ is geometrically integral, then $A=k$.

This gives that $k[X]=k$ and $\overline{k}[X]=\overline{k}$, and therefore $\overline{k}[X]^*=\overline{k}^*$.

The key facts for the proof are the fact that the pushforward of a coherent sheaf along a proper morphism is coherent ([02I5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O5)) and the fact that cohomology commutes with flat base extension ([02KE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KE)). With those in hand, we can play a few little games with $A$ to get the results.

---

As for your follow-up question regarding $k(X)^*$: no, that's not true. Try taking a look at $X=\Bbb P^n_k$, for instance - you shouldn't find it too hard to compute $k(X)^*$ in that case.

Comment: Thank you, the reference even has the geometrically integral condition, which I never knew was important in this case. For $X = \mathbb{P}^n_k$, the function field is the fraction field of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ right? So in the case where $X$ is proper, do we get any difference in $\bar{k}(X)^*$?

Comment: You're welcome. $\Bbb P^n_k$ is proper over $k$, so you should have your answer: $\overline{k}(X)^*\neq \overline{k}^*$.